# Количество знаков после запятой в JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Где и что нужно указать , что бы выводило 3 знака после запятой?

```
function razrap()
{ 
  document.getElementById('razmerrap').value =  parseFloat(document.getElementById('widDO').value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById('height').value)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[метод `toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

> форматирует число, используя запись с фиксированной запятой

```js
console.log(10.12345.toFixed(2));
console.log(10.12745.toFixed(2));
console.log(10.1.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: а где написать tofixed в моем коде?

Comment: @BigDaddy, лучше не стараться записать все в одну строку, а сохранить результат вычислений в переменную, потом присвоить значению инпута как `resultVar.toFixed(count)`